# Permalinks Issue - Running Wordpress on NGINX behind a reverse proxy that is also NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have 2 server instances running NGINX on both of them.

1. NGINX-A, it's the reverse proxy. It forwards traffic to different internal server depending on location block in its config
2. NGINX-B is a server instance where all of our PHP web apps are deployed.
3. Other server instances

So NGINX-A, receives all incoming traffic, reroutes it to the appropriate server. NGINX-B is a traditional Wordpress hosting running on NGINX instead of Apache.

---

I am trying to make **postname permalinks** work but have failed to do so.

My current directory structure:

```
/appl/wordpress/myblog == symbolic link ==> /usr/share/nginx/html/subdir/myblog
```

---

Here's my current config on the NGINX-B server where Wordpress is installed.

```
location /subdir/myblog/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/  /subdir/myblog/index.php?$args;
}
```

Accessing it via http://NGINX_B-ip_address/subdir/myblog works, both **postname permalinks** and **plain permalinks**. I did have to update wp-config as such below.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'NGINX_B-ip_address')
define('WP_SITEURL','NGINX_B-ip_address');
```

---

Now, I have another nginx server which acts as a reverse proxy, NGINX-A.

```
location /{
    proxy_pass http://NGINX_B-internal_ip_address;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    #for wordpress
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I also had to update wp-config.php with the new hostname

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog')
define('WP_SITEURL','http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog');
```

It works using **plain permalinks** and I can access wp-admin without any problem. I can also change the permalinks strategy.

If I don't use **plain permalinks**, the whole thing breaks and keep getting 404 error.

1. http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog - works
2. http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog/wp-admin - fully works
3. http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog/postname - fails | 404
4. http://NGINX-A-hostname/myblog/?p=postname - fully works

It's as if NGINX reverse proxy forwards the request as a directory rather than a parameter. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: May I ask, why are you using a separate nginx server to serve content as a  proxy from another nginx server/instance? If it's only for caching purposes you'd be better of just using nginx's FastCGI cache to act as a proxy with PHP-FPM for example, but on the same server. It's more performant and more reliable.

If you're doing it for another reason then can you indicate which permalink strategy are you trying to use which doesn't work, and which one are you using right now which does work?

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of `subdir` in your question - or how the `http://hostname/myblog` URI finds its way to `/subdir/myblog/`?

Comment: @ablopez Hi! I have updated the question to make it clear. Plain permalinks work in both ip address and hostname setup. Postname permalinks works only if accessed directly via IP.

Comment: OK, can you add an `exit('URI: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` to the functions.php file of the current theme in your NGINX-B WP setup, and then access a post page (using /%postname%/ permalinks) from it through NGINX-A, and let me know what URI is being received by WP in NGINX-B?

Comment: @ablopez Hi! I get 404 not found error. It seems like NGINX is treating anything after myblog/ as directory and not a parameter. Accessing wp-admin works without any problem.

Comment: OK, but is the 404 error nginx's default message for 404 errors coming from NGINX-A, or is it the 404 friendly error page coming from NGINX-B?

Comment: @ablopez It's not as simple as I thought it would be. I added a custom 404 page for both NGINX-A and NGINX-B. If NGINX-B returns error 404, NGINX-A displays upstream error as is. So I get an NGINX default 404 page. If I add proxy_intercept_errors in my config, I get my custom 404 error page specifically for NGINX-A. Does that make any sense?

Comment: OK, so the 404 error is coming from NGINX-B then? If so, then it should be returning WordPress' own error page, shouldn't it?

BTW, not sure if it may be the culprit but remember that WP validates the URL being requested against WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL, either if they're declared as constants, or if they're set in the wp_option table.

So if the WP site in NGINX-B is using the real hostname/domain, but you're requesting it from NGINX-A using NGINX-B's IP address, WP won't be able to match the requested URL against the actual domain set in the WP config. If this is the case let me know.

Comment: WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL is currently set to NGINX-A hostname. NGINX-A forwards request to NGINX-B as if it is coming directly from client itself that is why it has proxy_set_header Host $host; in the config. If anything is amiss, then I shouldn't be able to access the blog using any permalinks strategy.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok I managed to solve my issue by applying this to the NGINX-B server**

```
location /myblog {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/subdir;
        try_files $uri $uri/  /myblog/index.php?$args;
        location  ~ \.php$  {
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              fastcgi_index   index.php;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
              include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
}
```

---

My previous configuration was this and didn't work.

```
location /subdir/myblog/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/  /subdir/myblog/index.php?$args;
}
```

---

This also didn't work. Take not at the root entry. The myblog part should not be there and myblog should be included in try_files.

```
location /myblog {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/subdir/myblog;
    try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php?$args;
    location  ~ \.php$  {
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               fastcgi_index   index.php;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
       }
}
```